# querying different databases

Tags: php, mysqli

Maybe this is totally wrong to do, but...

I need to do a query like this:

> SELECT * FROM DATABASE1, DATABASE2 WHERE DATABASE1.users.name = DATABASE2.users.name

If I do it with phpmyadmin it works, but on php the page blocks.

The way I connect to mysql i'm using,

> $result = new mysqli(server, user, pass, database)

I can see why it doesn't work, I'm connecting to only one database, but how does phpmyadmin do it then?
How can I do it?

I've seen other posts but I want to CROSS the info on the 2 databases, and I havent found anything like that.

[EDIT]
An actual example of my code would be:

```
if($type == "past"){// Hago una query u otro dependiendo de si quiero pasados o futuros
             $query = "SELECT DISTINCT E.* FROM quehaceshoy_testing.Events E, quehaceshoy_testing.Tickets TK, quehaceshoy_testing.TypeTickets TT, quehaceshoy_testing.Tickets_Reservados2 TR, AirTicket.TICKET T WHERE ((T.Email='$this->email' AND T.idCompra = TR.idCompra AND TR.idTypeTicket_TypeTickets = TT.idTypeTicket AND E.IDEvent = TT.idEvent_Events)OR (E.email = '$this->email')) AND  E.dateFinish < '".$fecha."' ORDER BY E.dateFinish DESC";
        }
        else{
             $query = "SELECT DISTINCT E.* FROM quehaceshoy_testing.Events E, quehaceshoy_testing.Tickets TK, quehaceshoy_testing.TypeTickets TT, quehaceshoy_testing.Tickets_Reservados2 TR, AirTicket.TICKET T WHERE ((T.Email='$this->email' AND T.idCompra = TR.idCompra AND TR.idTypeTicket_TypeTickets = TT.idTypeTicket AND E.IDEvent = TT.idEvent_Events)OR (E.email = '$this->email')) AND  E.dateFinish >= '".$fecha."' ORDER BY E.dateFinish DESC";
        }
        //echo $query;
        //$result = $this->makeQuery($query, 'RESULT');
        if($conn = db_connect()){

                    $result = $conn->query($query);
                    if(!$result){
                      //echo '<p>Unable to get list from database.</p>';
                      //echo $conn->error;
                      return false;
                    }

        }
```

and db_connect is just:

```
function db_connect()
{
   $result = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, 'quehaceshoy_testing'); 
   $result->set_charset("utf8");

   if (!$result)
      return false;
   return $result;
}
```

This query makes the page to "load" indefinetly.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, to make understandable

Comment: Do you mean different databases or different tables?

Comment: I think the question is clear, he wants to get values from more tables, that are in different databases. Example query works in phpmyadmin, but not in mysqli php code.

Comment: thank you @Kyborek I think it's fairly clear.
Two databases ergo also 2 different tables, but both tables, from the different databases contain info that I want to match, it's possible in phpmyadmin, so it has to be posisble using PHP but I can't figure out how to do it in my code.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235264/how-to-connect-to-2-databases-at-the-same-time-in-php

Comment: Pl check both the above threads of discussion I posted above. You'd get your answer. You cannot query two databases with the same connection object. :)

Comment: Not really, since I want to cross them, as in the example. Making 2 conections would mean making a query for each of the values in table 1, from the first DB and then look for them in the second DB. I dont believe phpmyadmin does that, that's why I believe there's has to be another way.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question. The query example apparently not a real one and there is not a single hint on what "doesn't work" does actually mean.

Comment: According to this http://www.dottedidesign.com/node/14 it "just works" using SELECT db1.table.column, db2.table.column FROM db1.table, db2.table WHERE etc... Maybe just select one database or the other and give it a try.

Comment: Please be precise when you say the "page blocks". Is it that a blank page gets displayed? Or your browser cranks up into an infinite loop...

Comment: @DavidShaikh - yes, this is possible. Can we see some actual code, pasted into your question?

Answer (score 2):

I test-wrote a script below and it seems to be working fine without failing....

```
    <?php 
          $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
           mysql_select_db("test");

          $con1 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          mysql_select_db("test1");

           $query = "SELECT * FROM test1.`manager` INNER JOIN test.employee   
                    ON test1.`manager`.id= test.employee.mgr";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
           printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
          }
      ?>
```

May be you'll need to post your code here. Is it that your data set is large? Please post your code so that we may check and guide.